# Call function from outside jquery plugin - slimscroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, slimscroll

The code for the plugin is as follows,

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
          slimScroll: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
              ....
            };

            this.each(function() {
                function scrollContent(y, isWheel, isJump) {
                  ....
                }
              }
              return this;
            }
          }); jQuery.fn.extend({
          slimscroll: jQuery.fn.slimScroll
        });
```

How do i call the function scrollContent() from outside the plugin?

i have tried

`$("#myId").Slimscroll().ScrollContent();`

`$("#myId").data("SlimScroll").ScrollContent();`

And many other ways but dosent seem to get it working.

Comment: its a private method, it cannot be accessed from outside. Why would you want to access it at all ?

Comment: Well im adding items to the div and i would like to trigger that function. And while deleteing the items blank space is appearing. And on trigger of that some custom caluclations happens inside slimscroll.js and blank space will disappear so..

Comment: Could you please tell me how to make it public so that i can call it ?

Answer (score 0):

As the code shows `scrollContent` is a private method and is not supposed to be accessed from outside the plugin. Instead you could re-render the scrollbar by simply calling `$("#myId").slimScroll()` as shown in [this example](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/blob/master/examples/dynamic-content.html).

Comment: Tried that . But doesnt give me the desirable result. The scroll position would lose if i add/delete elements in between the div which contains the slimscroll.

Comment: And theres no way to know what the scroll position and the height of the scroll bar is , coz dynamically elements gets added.

Comment: Could you use `var top = $el.scrollTop();`? And after adding the elements `$el.slimScroll({ scrollTo: top })`